# CloudWatch Agent using SSM where instances are not showing in Managed Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, ssm

I was trying to install SSM agent in Ec2 instances for which i have attached instance role with SSM full access,CloudwatchagentAdmin role,SSM managed Instance core.But i could see my instances in SSM console of Managed Instances.

Anyone help ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

SSM agent is **installed by default** on:

- Amazon Linux 1 and 2
- Ubuntu Server 16.04 and 18.04
- Amazon ECS-Optimized

Thus, there is no need to manually install it, if you use any of these system. Nevertheless, general things to check/consider for the lack of recognition as managed instance are:

1. Check your **instance role**. Good start for the role is one which includes `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` managed policy.
2. Verify  **internet connectivity** of your instance. The instance must be able to communicate with the SSM service. This is especially important if the instance is in a custom VPC. If this is the case, then:

   - Check if the instance is in **private subnet** or a public subnet.
   - If private, then have to *correctly* setup **NAT gateway/instance** or **SSM VPC Interface endpoint** to be able to communicate with the SSM service.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the SSM Agent is not started.

> - Run the following command to determine if SSM Agent is running:
>
>   `sudo snap list amazon-ssm-agent`
> - Run the following command to start the service if the previous command returned amazon-ssm-agent is stopped, inactive, or disabled:
>
>   `sudo snap start amazon-ssm-agent`
> - Check the status of the agent:
>
>   `sudo snap services amazon-ssm-agent`

See [AWS Systems Manager docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/agent-install-ubuntu.html) for more details.